# How can I make my J2EE web application work offline?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to make my web application able to work offline and as soon as it becomes online or gets connected again, then it should be able to transfer the modifications made by user in offline mode.

I have seen [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) as an ideal solution for my problem, which is not recommended to be used as it is now deprecated.

What is a good way to make my application work offline, both in terms of technology to use and application design?

Comment: You can try an alternative. For example ,a flash application used for offline mode. While a web application used for online mode.

Comment: Offline storage is overrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gears is deprecated because the HTML5 standard allows for equivalent features to be present in compliant browsers.

With respect to your current problem at hand of handling offline web application access, you can look into the support offered by [HTML5 for offline web applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/) via support for [client-side SQL database access](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/#sql), and the [client-side application HTTP cache](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/#offline).

The features will have to be used in conjunction, as the client-side database access will allow for storage of data (generated when the application is offline) in a structured format, while the offline application cache will allow for caching of HTTP responses from the server; you should not be caching responses that are dynamic in nature which depend on any user-provided inputs.

The details of the proposed APIs can be found in the [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#offline), which is in draft at the moment, although it appears that certain user-agents have already implemented this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will need some form of offline storage. HTML5's capabilities are the successor to Google Gears, as stated on the [google gears developer blog](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/stopping-gears.html); essentially, the purpose of Google Gears was just to push the development & subsequent adoption of HTML 5 features.

Specifically you should be looking at the [HTML5 offline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html) ([here's a tutorial](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html)) APIs, and the [Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) APIs may also come in handy ([relevant tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html)).

With regards to design, you will essentially need to maintain your complete web application state client side, and then send over the differences (i.e. update the server-side state) as soon as the connection to the server is available again.

Off the top of my head, there's 2 simple ways to design this:

1. Explicitly maintain separate application states for the client and server. Essentially, when the user takes an action, it's applied to the client application state first, and then at specified intervals (and/or triggers, e.g. the user clicks the save button), the client sends over the differences between the last known state of the server and the current state of the client. This is probably best suited to highly interactive web applications, and I suspect Google Docs works on this kind of design. Depending on your application (if "conflicting changes" can occur), you'll need to also account for merging application state: do you override with the last received client state, or do you intelligently try to merge? (you'll have to decide which makes more sense for your particular application.)
2. Record user actions while offline, and replay them once the connection becomes available again. You essentially implement the [Command design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), and have both your client-side code and server-side code able to handle each command. The client-side code always handles each command, and while the connection to the server is available, your client side code also sends off the commands to the server. You'll probably want to implement some batching, to avoid continual requests to the server, and also some roll-back functionality when requests to the server fail (e.g. conflicting changes). This ends up looking more or less like GMail's main email managment user interface, where you can undo operations.

Answer (score 0):

This has not much to do with J2EE, but rather how you code your web-client. One possible solution would be to use a javascript client that does save the data in the local storage introduced with html5 (see http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html ). That is also basically the reason why google gears was stopped ...

Comment: I have seen those friend but if the cache of the browser is cleared then it would not work. this is one of the loopback in this.